# Can you use gpiozero wait_for_press() inside of a callback triggered by add_event_detect?

Tags: gpio, audio, rpi.gpio, gpiozero

I am trying to write a script that uses a GPIO interrupt to callback a function that starts by playing a sound and then waits for a button to be pressed to start recording a sound, and then waits for another button press to stop the recording and leave the function and be ready for the callback to be made.

My code is below. I am not including all of the functions I am using, I'm just wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to use the gpiozero module's `wait_for_press` function inside of a GPIO `add_event_callback`. When I run it I get a Segmentation Fault, so I'm thinking no. It seems to be the `GPIO.cleanup()` that causes the Segmentation Fault. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(play_button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

rec = Recorder(channels=2)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

play_button = 23

def rec_pack():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    play_sound() #The function that runs as soon as the rec_pack() is called
    GPIO.cleanup()#the GPIO.cleanup is the part that seems to be triggering the Segmentation Fault
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    record_button = Button(16)
    stop_button = Button(26)
    record_button.wait_for_press() #this is the gpiozero function to wait for the second  button to be pressed to start the recording
    with rec.open('output.wav', 'wb') as r:
        r.start_recording()
        stop_button.wait_for_press() #and this is waiting for the third button to be pressed to stop the recording
        r.stop_recording()

#Defining the callback function
def button_released_callback(channel):
    rec_pack()

#Setting up the event listener
GPIO.add_event_detect(play_button, GPIO.RISING,
                      callback=button_released_callback,
                      bouncetime=150)

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i don't know.  Do you mean gpiozero rather than RPo.GPIO.  I suggest you find an alternative solution.  In a callback I suggest just setting a flag saying the event happened.  Do all the needed waits etc. in the main thread (your current while/sleep part).

Answer (score 0):

Interrupts should do the minimum of processing. (This is true in general but more so in python.) Including ANY delay in a callback is a poor practice.

It depends on your program logic but only one will be active at a time.

RPi.GPIO callbacks run in a single thread.

It is unclear what your incomplete code fragment is supposed to do but it isn't gpiozero.

You should NOT mix RPi.GPIO and gpiozero code.

Comment: Thank you Milliways and @joan for your advice. I'm going to step back and rethink how I'm doing this based on your thoughts, as it sounds like my current path is not going to work. I'll share my code once I've got it running or have more questions!